# Using Selenium to scrape laptop information from dell website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to use `selenium` to download laptop information (i.e. make, model, price, graphics card etc.) from the Dell website. My aim is to do this with several retailers and compile a list of all unique laptops that I can find.

The following code will open chrome at the correct website, but I am unsure of the best strategy for actually pulling down the information I want.

```
from selenium import webdriver

#launch url
url = "https://www.dell.com/en-uk/work/shop/scc/sc/laptops?~ck=mn"

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: go over the HTML and search for the pattern in which the laptops are arranged in. from a brief looking at the website, I can see that each laptop is in a <div> tag and have the description and details inside. Find the proper HTML tags you should iterate

Comment: You could do this with BeautifulSoup in my opinion its simpler and more suited to what you want to do, selenium is more for testing.

Comment: I suggest you use ```requests``` with ```BeautifulSoup``` to download and extract the data much faster. Either way you can view the page source and get a general idea of where the information is located, and use libraries like ```BeautifulSoup``` or ```re``` to extract them.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys. I have turned to BeautifulSoup in the end and I've got the ball rolling.